# SQL execute a request in a stored procedure depending on the value of a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How do I execute a SQL statement depending on the value of a variable inside a stored procedure?

```
if(@Quantity <= @MaxAuto) then Exec(@ReqSQL) else do nothing;
```

Comment: Is @ReqSQL going to contain the name of a stored procedure, or will it by DSQL (Dynamic SQL)?

If DSQL - be cautious of SQL Injection.

If Stored procedures, then you may be able to get away with creating an If/Begin/End/ElseIf/...  block as suggested by AntDC's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were practically there...

```
if(@Quantity <= @MaxAuto) 
BEGIN
  Exec StoredProcName @param1, @Param2, etc, etc
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ReqSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ReqSQL = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE'

IF(@Quantity <= @MaxAuto) 
BEGIN 
 EXEC (@ReqSQL) 
END
```

Comment: shouldn't that be, `exec sp_executesql @ReqSql;`?

Comment: I found someExec(@ReqSQL) in another SP and it works fine